# How to convert richTextBox strings into integers and sum them into a total RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have 4 richtextboxes and all of them contain numbers. I also have a TOTAL. How can I sum them I've tried many methods and nothing seems to work.

They are:
richTextBox17

richTextBox18

richTextBox19

richTextBox20

the total is:
richTextBox21

textbox17 = 11.550,00

textbox18 = 1.332,80

textbox19 = 775,50

textbox20 = 131,32

```cs
private void textBox23_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val1 = Int32.Parse(richTextBox17.Text);
    int val2 = Int32.Parse(richTextBox18.Text);
    int val3 = Int32.Parse(richTextBox19.Text);
    int val4 = Int32.Parse(richTextBox20.Text);
    textBox23.Text = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
}
```

Also tried:

```cs
double val1 = (double)decimal.Parse(richTextBox17.Text.Replace(",", ""));
double val2 = (double)decimal.Parse(richTextBox18.Text.Replace(",", ""));
double val3 = (double)decimal.Parse(richTextBox19.Text.Replace(",", ""));
double val4 = (double)decimal.Parse(richTextBox20.Text.Replace(",", ""));

double sum = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4);

textBox23.Text = sum.ToString();
```

In this method there are no errors but the `sum` is wrong.

Comment: The name you have assigned (or, you forgot to assign) to your Controls doesn't matter, their content does. Post a sample of the *numbers* you have in your Controls and what you have tried to generate a *total* from these *numbers*.

Comment: `11.550,00` you got a wrong fromat ? why is it reverse

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I am seeing that just now

Comment: You have to treat those *numbers* as `decimal` values, since it appears those represent currency. You have `decimal.TryParse()` for this. Specify the correct CultureInfo as the `IFormatProvider`.

Comment: "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Because that method doesn't take just one argument. Put the caret over `.TryParse()` and press `F1`, you'll see the related documentation.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales

Comment: The simplest form is `var v1 = decimal.Parse([Some TextBox].Text, NumberStyles.Currency);`, then sum the values, the show the result as: `[Total TextBox].Text =  total.ToString("N2");` -- This assumes the current culture uses a dot as decimal separator and comma  as thousands separator, if this is not the case, you have to use the overload that allows to specify a CultureInfo, as in `var culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");` (since, for example, Spain uses that form), then use the overload:  `var v1 = decimal.Parse([Some TextBox].Text, NumberStyles.Currency, culture);`

Comment: If the text comes from user input, you have to use `decimal.TryParse()` instead, which allows to validate the input value:, e.g, `if (decimal.TryParse([Some TextBox].Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentColture, out decimal value1) { // valid value }` -- You can find many example in the MSDN documentation and here.

Comment: You could also use `double.Parse()` or `double.TryParse()` here, but the total value may be subject to rounding. If you use decimal, the total is `13789.62`, if you use double, it's `13789.619999999999`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qzuk8H

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to int in order to sum those value in richtextBox
It  could be `int` `long` `double` etc..

```
double val1 = double.Parse(richTextBox18.Text.Replace(",",""));
double val2 = double.Parse(richTextBox19.Text.Replace(",",""));
double val3 = double.Parse(richTextBox12.Text.Replace(",",""));
double sum = val1+val2+val3;


richTextBox21.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and I have gotten the error  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: I edited my answer, see above changes

Comment: Hey, "Exception unhandled" "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: `11.550,00` can you explain this ? it should be something like `11,550.00` right ?

Comment: Yes, it should. I've changed it to 11,550.00 and I still have the same error.

Comment: See above changes again, the answer was a common or basic thing to do

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can you change `double.Parse` to `Convert.ToDouble` ? If still got an error you need to add `.00` int your richTextBox Format

Comment: I did, it did not work. I have the same error as the last one.

Comment: Please check my update.